# Setting up Notepad++ Compare as the diff tool in git?

Tags: git, diff, notepad++

Is there an easy way to setup Notepad++'s Compare plugin as the diff tool for Git on Windows?  I'm not sure whether it can be called from the command line so maybe not.

Comment: You know git has a built-in diff tool, right? What's wrong with that?

Comment: I like the way the Notepad++ Compare looks more. If it's not an option I can use something else, wanted to see if it was an option though

Comment: This question has a correct answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38823833/227755).

Comment: Why would you do that? Compare is visually and by compare quality inferior in diff quality to git / tortoise git tools

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, Notepad++ doesn't allow custom command-line options for its plugins, so it would be a tad tricky to do so. You would need to create a wrapper script for it or call the executable directly. In my humble opinion, not worth it given that there are some very nice options for diff tools out there.

In any case, `git difftool` allows you to specify what exactly you'd like git to use for diff. You'll add this to your `.gitconfig` file:

```
[diff]
tool = araxis // enter your tool of choice here, Araxis is just an example
```

If you'd like to read more about it, here's a link to the man page: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-difftool.html

Comment: It's a messy workaround, but you can copy your diff paths from another difftool, such as Meld, open them in side-by-side views in Notepad++, and then run the Compare plugin.

Answer (score 3):

I've just posted a solution to a similar question [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170541/running-notepad-from-command-line-with-compare-plugin-showing-compare-result). Btw, one of the main points in preferring N++ as a diff viewer is, for instance, that if you're anyway handling Git-managed code in N++, then you can always directly "Compare against GIT base" (v1.5.6.3!). Another reason is of course looking at a diff in a "real" editor with syntax highlighting and all the other well known goodies at hand.

Answer (score 2):

Since ComparePlus is out, it is actually easily possible to set it up as the git difftool.

ComparePlus is the successor of Compare, I set it up with version 1.1 installed from the Plugins Admin.

In your .gitconfig file, add the following lines (adjust the path to notepad++.exe, if you installed it elsewhere):

```
[diff]
tool = npp_compareplus

[difftool]
prompt = false

[difftool "npp_compareplus"]
cmd = \"C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\" -multiInst -nosession -pluginMessage=compare \"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\"
```

`-multiInst` will start the diff in a new window, `-nosession` will open the new window without any other files open of your old/other session and `-pluginMessage=compare` tells npp to use the ComparePlus and let's it know of the arguments for the local/remote file.

Comment: Here is the GitHub repository of the ComparePlus plugin: https://github.com/pnedev/comparePlus And here a forum post where a user had the same idea: https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/post/79818 You can also use it as diff tool for 7-Zip File manager by putting `START /B C:\PROGRA~1\Notepad++\notepad++.exe -multiInst -nosession -pluginMessage=compare %1 %2` into a .bat file and setting it as compare program in the options. (Enter the .bat path manually, though, as the file chooser only allows to select .exes)