# How do I use Notepad++ Compare as the diff tool in git bash/command line?

Tags: git, bash, notepad++, diff

Is there any way to change the default diff tool in gitbash?

This post seems to suggest it is possible but they provided no command line examples. Link: [Running NotePad++ from Command line with Compare Plugin showing compare result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170541/running-notepad-from-command-line-with-compare-plugin-showing-compare-result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the official diff plugin for Notepad++ seems to be [`uph0/compare`](https://bitbucket.org/uph0/compare/), a possible setting could be:

```
$ git config --global --add diff.guitool nppdiff
$ git config --global --add difftool.nppdiff.path "C:/Program Files/Notepad++/plugins/ComparePlugin/compare.exe"
$ git config --global --add difftool.nppdiff.trustExitCode false
```

Comment: Alright. I've executed the above commands. But when I use "diff 1.txt 2.txt" it still uses the default diff. Am I supposed to use a different command?

Comment: Are you typing diff or git diff?

Comment: diff (Not comparing against commits)

Comment: @sephiith you can compare against file (not commit or even not a git repo) with: `git diff --no-index -- file1 file2` (again, `file1` and `file2` can be anywhere, completely unrelated to any git repo). Since it is a `git diff` command, it can use the `guitool` and `difftool` you specify for Git, even though the `--no-index` allows `git diff` to be used outside a git repo.