# Using Notepad++ diff tool for git

Tags: git, notepad++

I would like to set the diff tool of Notepad++ to be used as the diff tool invoked when I do a git diff of files. The Google searches produce various things, with [How do I use Notepad++ Compare as the diff tool in git bash/command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38823392/how-do-i-use-notepad-compare-as-the-diff-tool-in-git-bash-command-line/38823833) often as the top search result.

That page's `git config` commands refer to a file that I do not have, namely Compare.exe, in the Notepad++ installation directories. When I do a compare from within Notepad++, it works fine. So is `Compare.exe` the result of installing some extra compare plugin? Notepad++ compare operations show up under the `plugins` menu there, so I thought I had the (a?) compare plugin installed.

Answer (score 0):

Only way I could find is a workaround.

Compare Plugin does not include the external launcher `compare.exe` anymore. But git needs a mechanism like this to set N++ as a diff tool. With a bit of effort though it is still possible to do. Tested with Notepad++ v8.1.5(64bit) and Compare Plugin v2.0.1.

1. Install Compare Plugin via Notepad's Plugins Admin option. (Update N++ when missing).
2. Compile this [project](https://bitbucket.org/uph0/compare/src/master/loader/) to get `compare.exe` file.
   Place it somewhere. I chose `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\ComparePlugin\ComparePlugin\compare.exe`.

(Note: Pre-compiled version found in [downloads](https://bitbucket.org/uph0/compare/downloads/) did not work for me. You need to have the latest build).

By now Notepad++ should start when running `compare.exe fileA.txt fileB.txt`.

Setting up git to use it.

```
git config --global diff.tool nppdiff
git config --global difftool.nppdiff.cmd "'C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\ComparePlugin\ComparePlugin\compare.exe' \$LOCAL \$REMOTE"
```

Your .gitconfig file should now look like this.

```
[diff]
  tool = nppdiff
[difftool "nppdiff"]
  cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\plugins\\ComparePlugin\\ComparePlugin\\compare.exe' $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

Now `git difftool -y` will open Notepad++.